# Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'void'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I've been trying to convert a UnityScript into C#, but I'm getting errors. The following is my source code:

```
 GameObject spine;
 private float z = 0;
 private float ySpeed = 13.0f;
 private float zMinLimit = -40.00f;
 private float zMaxLimit = 40.00f;

 void LateUpdate() {
     z -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed;
     z = ClampAngle(z, zMinLimit, zMaxLimit);
     Quaternion rotation_bone = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -z);
     spine.transform.localRotation = rotation_bone;
 }

 static void ClampAngle (float angle, float min, float max) {
     if (angle < -360){
         angle += 360;
     }
     if (angle > 360){
         angle -= 360;
     }
     return Mathf.Clamp (angle, min, max);
 }
```

The line that causes the compiler error is:

```
z = ClampAngle(z, zMinLimit, zMaxLimit);
```

with the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'float'

A second line throws two additional compiler errors.

```
return Mathf.Clamp (angle, min, max);
```

> 'rotateBones.ClampAngle(float, float, float): a return keyword must not be followed by an expression when a method returns void
>
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'void'

I understand the float to void and void to float errors from my coding background, I just don't know how to fix these two in C#.

Comment: Your return type for the `ClampAngle` definition says it's returning `void`. You're actually returning `float`. Fix the return type and it should work.

Comment: That's my concern. I know what the error is, I just don't know how to convert that value. I tried casting (float) ClampAngle(z, zMinLimit, zMaxLimit); and it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using C# a void is used to define a method that returns no value, so in order for it to comply to C# syntax, the method type of void cannot contains that return line. However, by changing void to a variable type or class, such as int, bool, float, string, etc..., you can have it return that type. So in your case you are returning a Mathf.Clamp of three floats, which would be returning a float. So your new code would look like this:

```
public GameObject spine;
private float z = 0;
private float ySpeed = 13.0f;
private float zMinLimit = -40.00f;
private float zMaxLimit = 40.00f;

void LateUpdate() {
    z -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed;
    z = ClampAngle(z, zMinLimit, zMaxLimit);
    Quaternion rotation_bone = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -z);
    spine.transform.localRotation = rotation_bone;
}

static float ClampAngle (float angle, float min, float max) {
    if (angle < -360){
        angle += 360;
    }
    if (angle > 360){
        angle -= 360;
    }
    return Mathf.Clamp (angle, min, max);
}
```

A simple fix but a must know for when programming in C#.
**Edit:**
As for the null reference exception you were describing in the comments of the other answer, it is because the GameObject spine is not defined or declared as public or private. Make the GameObject public and define it in the inspector.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about the error because I do have a programming background. The fix was making the spine public. The code now works fine. I have marked this as solved. :)